# What is the different between GDR security update and CU security update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, patching

What is the different between GDR security update and CU security update?

I am looking to understand difference between the below two updates. If I apply KB3194724, would it also include KB 3194721?

1. Build 11.00.6567 (3194724 MS16-136: Description of the security update for SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 3 CU: November 8, 2016)

AND

2. Build 11.0.6248.0 (3194721 MS16-136: Description of the security update for SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 3 GDR: November 8, 2016) for SQL Server 2012?

Which one should I apply if SQL Server 2012 is on SP3?

Comment: My favorite site when it comes to reviewing SQL Updates and Builds is https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/.  Another good one is https://sqlserverupdates.com/ which is maintained by Brent Ozar.

Comment: Another good one is: https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 4):

You should install the latest CU for SQL 2012 SP3.

As of today (10 May 2017) it is [CU8](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50733)

The SQL version number will give you a good indication of what is more recent.

An explanation of what GDR means can be found [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mrsnrub/2009/05/14/gdr-qfe-ldr-wth/).

Answer (score 0):

Latest one is sufficient to apply at SQLServer 2008 R2 SP3 as it will cover everything.I recommend you to apply  Build 11.00.6567 (3194724 MS16-136: Description of the security update for SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 3 CU: November 8, 2016). Wherever the version is high then we can consider it as SQL Server subsystem is up to date with patches.